# Undefined method which is not used

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello i'm new one in ruby on rails. I have strange problem. I use some tutorial and get error which i shouldn't get.

I have controller

```
class DiaryController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!

respond_to :html, :xml, :json
respond_to :js, :only => [:create, :update, :destroy]

def create
@record = Record.create(record_params)
@record.userId=current_user.id

if request.xhr? || remotipart_submitted?
  sleep 1 if params[:pause]
  render :layout => false, :template => (params[:template] == 'escape' ? 'comments/escape_test' : 'diary/create'), :status => (@record.errors.any? ? :unprocessable_entity : :ok)
else
  redirect_to diary_path
end
end

def add
@record = Record.new
#respond_with(@record, :layout => false)
respond_with do |format|
  format.html { render :layout => ! request.xhr? }
end
end

# PUT /comments/1
# PUT /comments/1.xml
def update
  @record = Record.find(params[:id])
  respond_with do |format|
  format.html{ redirect_to @record }
end
end

def delete
  @comment = Comment.destroy(params[:id])
end

def edit
  @record = Record.find(params[:id])
end

def index
  @records = Record.where(userId: current_user.id)
end

private

def record_params
  params.require(:record).permit(:photo, :comment, :date, :photo_cache)
end
```

end

Have view

```
<h1 align="centre">
  Добавить запись
</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Отмена', diary_path, :id => 'cancel-button' %>
```

and

```
<%= form_for(@record, :remote => (params[:action] == 'add' ? true : false)) do |f| %>

<fieldset>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date, :class => 'required' %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :comment %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= image_tag(@record.photo_url(:thumb)) if @record.photo? %><br />
    <%= f.label :photo %><br/>
    <%= f.file_field :photo %><br/>
    <%= f.hidden_field :photo_cache %>
  </div>

 </fieldset>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Добавить", :data => {:'disable-with' => "Submitting..."} %>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to 'Отмена', diary_path, :id => 'cancel-button' %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And get ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `records_path' for #<#:0x000000054461c8>): error on "<%= form_for(@record, :remote => (params[:action] == 'add' ? true : false)) do |f| %>" line. Even records_path i did'n use.

I Have routes

```
devise_for :users
get 'welcome/index'
root 'welcome#index'
get 'diary' => 'diary#index'
get 'diary/add_record', to: 'diary#add', as: 'add_record'
post 'diary/add_record', to: 'diary#create'
get 'diary/edit_record/:id', to: 'diary#edit'
delete 'diary/edit_record/:id' => 'diary#delete
```

And and try to use add_record route. Maybe it would be better to use resources :records.But i want to figure out why my routes doesn't work.

view name "diary".

Comment: what path you want to use...? i m seeing u are using @record = Record.new, so rails will automatically map it to records controller create action. unless u add custom url in  your form.

Comment: What is your view file name?

Comment: I edit my question to clarify what you've asked

Comment: Is your view name is `diary.html.erb`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're new to RoR, let me explain why you're receiving the error

---

[**form_for**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object)

`form_for` is the *likely* reason why you're receiving this error (oh, I just saw it actually states this is where the error occurs - sweet)

The problem you have is that `form_for` is meant as a way to render a form *around* an ActiveRecord object. It's mean to give some semi-persistence to the data, by using AR in both the `new` and `create` actions (allowing you to show the in-putted data on the form after submission)

When you pass an object to `form_for`, Rails automatically "builds" the form from the ActiveRecord object, one of the options it uses being the [`url`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

--

**Routes**

The problem you have is the object you pass to the `form_for` takes the `model_name` attribute to build the route. This means if you want to use the `form_for` method by just passing an object, it's going to look for routes pertaining directly to that object

If you don't have any `[model]_path` route set up, you'll likely receive the error you're getting. The fix firstly involves the **routes**, and secondly involves the **controller**:

```
#config/routes.rb
root 'welcome#index'
devise_for :users

resources :diary, path_names: { new: "add_record", create: "add_record", edit: "edit_record", destroy: "edit_record" }
resources :welcome, only: :index
```

This is down to the idea that Rails' routing structure is [built around *resources*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) - every route you have should lead to a specific controller action. Whilst including custom actions is completely fine, you have to appreciate that the basis of the routing structure is to construct `resourceful` routing, which essentially means that Rails perceives every controller / model to have corresponding routes:

[image]

--

**URL**

The second thing to observe is the `url` of the form

If you have your routes set up as above, and if your routing structure differs from your model structure (different names), you'll want to use the following setup to define the `url` explicitly:

```
<%= form_for @record, url: your_custom_path do |f| %>
```